# Unwanted keys in SQlite3 $rows

Tags: php, database, sqlite

If a row in my SQlite3 table called 'data' looks like this:

```
Gorilla|10|Black
```

And I'm getting it with this PHP:

```
$returned = array();

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data");

foreach($result as $row) {
    $returned[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($returned);
```

The resulting parsed JS Object in Array looks like this:

```
[{
  0: Gorilla,
  1: 10,
  2: Black,
  Age: 10,
  Animal: Gorilla,
  Color: Black
}]
```

Why are there 6 properties yet only 3 columns in the DB? I would like to be rid of the first 3 properties of the object and return only:

```
[{
  Age: 10,
  Animal: Gorilla,
  Color: Black
}]
```

How? :)

Comment: Read the manual and use `SQLITE_ASSOC` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of `SQLiteDatabase::query`. As specified in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php):

> The optional *result_type* parameter accepts a constant and determines how the returned array will be indexed. Using `SQLITE_ASSOC` will return only associative indices (named fields) while `SQLITE_NUM` will return only numerical indices (ordinal field numbers). `SQLITE_BOTH` will return both associative and numerical indices. `SQLITE_BOTH` is the default for this function.

So write:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data", SQLITE_ASSOC);
```

## EDIT for PDO

As you connect using PDO, the syntax becomes:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: What you said to write is default behavior. ^^ You'd want to put `$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data", SQLITE_ASSOC);`

Comment: When I attempt to use SQLITE_ASSOC I receive the following error:
Use of undefined constant SQLITE_ASSOC - assumed 'SQLITE_ASSOC' @trincot can you please tell me why?

Comment: Try `SQLITE3_ASSOC` (with "3"). It depends on PHP version.

Comment: Cool. Got passed that error, however now the resulting object looks like: {Age: null, Animal: null, Color: null} ? :/ @trincot

Comment: OK, remove that parameter again, and instead add it in the while loop, like this: `while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: same deal, values are null :( @trincot

Comment: Yes, without the SQLITE3_ASSOC flag the values are populated no problems.

Comment: Show me the line where you connect to the database. It should be like `$db = new SQLite3($databaseName);`

Comment: I'm using `$db = new PDO('sqlite:test.db');` as for some reason `$db = new SQLite3('test.db');` does not work at all for me, setting or retrieving db content.

Comment: Try using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` then. ^^

Comment: @trincot Haha! Sorry, saw you had replied and came back to respond to you before I saw the entire conversation. Knowing it was PDO would have helped greatly from the beginning. ^^

Comment: Apparently `1` is the magic value in `php8.1-sqlite3`--good reason not to rely on them. `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` was defined, but returned a normal array and `SQLITE_ASSOC` was undefined.